# Speeding up pan-sharpening with OTB plugin for QGIS (orfeo-toolbox)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, landsat-8, orfeo-toolbox, pansharpening

I use QGIS 3.6.1 with the plugin [orfeo-toolbox](https://gitlab.orfeo-toolbox.org/orfeotoolbox/qgis-otb-plugin) to create a pan-sharped Landsat 8 image. I use the [BundleToPerfectSensor](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_BundleToPerfectSensor.html) function because calling the [Pansharpening](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_Pansharpening.html.) function results to the error: `Inputs are not occupy the same physical space!`

The problem is that execution with default parameters is extremely slow - more than **2 hours and 30 minutes** (even after adding memory to the OTB plugin - 1024 mb).

**How long does it take to *you* to create a pan-sharp Landsat 8 image using the QGIS OTB plugin?**

**Do you use the default settings?**

My logs:

```` Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'BundleToPerfectSensor' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'inp' : 'G:/!DELETE/testing_pansharp/LC08_L1TP_160017_20180716_20180730_01_T1/LC08_L1TP_160017_20180716_20180730_01_T1_B8.TIF', 
'inxs' : 'G:/!DELETE/testing_pansharp/LC08_L1TP_160017_20180716_20180730_01_T1/RGB.tif', 
'out' : 'G:/!DELETE/testing_pansharp/LC08_L1TP_160017_20180716_20180730_01_T1/PAN_full.tif',
'elev.dem' : '', 
'elev.geoid' : '', 
'elev.default' : 0, 
'mode' : 'default', 
'method' : 'bayes', 
'method.bayes.lambda' : 0.9999, 
'method.bayes.s' : 1, 
'lms' : 4, 
'interpolator' : 'nn', 
'fv' : 0, 
'outputpixeltype' : 1 
}
2019-10-17 17:20:57 (INFO): No kwl metadata found in file G:/!DELETE/testing_pansharp/LC08_L1TP_160017_20180716_20180730_01_T1/RGB.tif
2019-10-17 17:20:57 (INFO): No kwl metadata found in file G:/!DELETE/testing_pansharp/LC08_L1TP_160017_20180716_20180730_01_T1/LC08_L1TP_160017_20180716_20180730_01_T1_B8.TIF
2019-10-17 17:20:57 (INFO): Default RAM limit for OTB is 1024 MB
2019-10-17 17:20:57 (INFO): GDAL maximum cache size is 812 MB
2019-10-17 17:20:57 (INFO): OTB will use at most 8 threads
2019-10-17 17:20:57 (INFO): Reproject XS onto Pan...
2019-10-17 17:20:57 (INFO): Elevation management: setting default height above ellipsoid to 0 meters
2019-10-17 17:20:57 (INFO): Fusion of XS and Pan...
2019-10-17 17:20:57 (INFO): Bayesian fusion algorithm
2019-10-17 17:20:57 (INFO): Estimated memory for full processing: 12196.3MB (avail.: 1024 MB), optimal image partitioning: 12 blocks
2019-10-17 17:20:57 (INFO): File G:/!DELETE/testing_pansharp/LC08_L1TP_160017_20180716_20180730_01_T1/PAN_full.tif will be written in 13 blocks of 16361x1270 pixels

2019-10-17 17:32:17 (INFO): Estimation will be performed in 11 blocks of 16361x1501 pixels
2019-10-17 20:04:20 (INFO): Estimated memory for full processing: 10136.5MB (avail.: 1024 MB), optimal image partitioning: 10 blocks
2019-10-17 20:04:20 (INFO): Estimation will be performed in 11 blocks of 16361x1501 pixels
2019-10-17 22:37:53 (INFO): Estimated memory for full processing: 13226.1MB (avail.: 1024 MB), optimal image partitioning: 13 blocks
2019-10-17 22:37:53 (INFO): Estimation will be performed in 14 blocks of 16361x1179 pixels```
2019-10-18 01:14:02 (INFO): Estimated memory for full processing: 5149.29MB (avail.: 1024 MB), optimal image partitioning: 6 blocks
2019-10-18 01:14:02 (INFO): Estimation will be performed in 7 blocks of 16361x2358 pixels
Execution completed in 37821.38 seconds
Results:
{'out': 'G:/!DELETE/testing_pansharp/LC08_L1TP_160017_20180716_20180730_01_T1/PAN_full.tif'}
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'BundleToPerfectSensor' finished ````

Comment: *(I use Monteverdi, not QGIS-OTB so this may be different)* Usually I do it in two steps: 1- Superimpose, 2- Pansharpening. OTB is fussy about grid alignment. I can give only 256Mb of RAM but it works anyway.

Comment: @Kazuhito How long does it take to complete a single scene?

Comment: For a scene of L8(B4/B3/B2+B8), Composite: 37 sec, Superimpose 258 sec, Pansharpen 190 sec. (Windows10 on Intel Core i5, 2.0 GHz, 2 cores, 4GB RAM).

Comment: @Kazuhito It took more than 2.5 horus to complete with `BundleToPerfectSensor` function. My PC is faster than yours: i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40Ghz, 4 cores, 16 GB RAM. OTB Results are: Composite: 11 sec, Superimpose 78 sec, Pansharpen 142 sec. Perhaps sometning wrong with the QGIS OTB Plugin. I will create issue for this problem. Thx for you comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is a bug because execution `BundleToPerfectSensor` with OTB's `mapla.bat` took only 359 seconds.

Here is my issue for this bug:
https://gitlab.orfeo-toolbox.org/orfeotoolbox/qgis-otb-plugin/issues/35

Comment: When you run through command line, do you set any `-ram` parameter ?.

Comment: @rkm No. But when I run with OTB - Yes, I set memory to 1024.

Comment: IIUC, if using mapla.bat, you don' set any RAM parameter but using QGIS you set it.  Is that correct ?. If so please try to unset RAM parameter in Settings -> Processing -> Providers -> OTB. You can unset either by clear the value of field or setting it to a value < 256.

Comment: @rkm I did what you asked, and I confirm that it still takes more than 20 minutes to process one Landsat 8 scene. (I stop the process because can't wait anymore).

Answer (score 1):

RCS method (default) is fast, but poor result.
Bayes method is better, but the price to pay is the processing time. 
The pansharpening application requires that the xs image is resampled on the same physical grid as pan.
The BundleToPerfectSensor performs the resampling and  the pansharpening in one pass.